# Why is the transition: background red in syntax highlighting (Visual Studio)?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I am a teacher and had a student ask why the "background" is red in color. This is in Visual Studio Code using the Dark+ theme. I have tried looking in the settings for syntax highlighting to identify different colors, but haven't had any luck. Same with browsing the web for this theme's color usage.

[image]

Comment: Thank you both, here is a follow up question.

You both have either stated it is invalid or not animatable, however, I have always used w3schools as a reference for my students. This link here states that the background attribute is animatable. 

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp#:~:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,%2C%20numbers%2C%20percentage%20and%20color.

So is my code editor wrong, is w3schools wrong, or is this a case of it used to be one way or the other and now the current version of HTML has changed it so, again one of the two things are wrong?

Comment: Indeed, looking at both W3C and MDN docs it looks like the ``background`` property is on the list of animatable properties and isn't deprecated. My limited guess here is that the issue comes from VSCode ``textmate scopes`` which shouldn't be triggering the ``invalid.deprecated.color.system.css`` scope for that property.

Answer (score 4):

`background` is not an animatable property. More on this [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animation-of-property-types-).

You may use `background-color` instead.

Answer (score 4):

##### Answer

The syntax is red because VSCode marked it as **invalid/deprecated** code, and the Dark+ theme has this scope set to `#F44747` (red).

[image: Example]

---

##### Override default style

In case you're looking to change the default `foreground` (color) or the default `fontStyle` of this scope, you can go to vscode command prompt and select `Open settings (JSON)` then add the following :

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "[Default Dark+]": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": ["invalid.deprecated.color.system.css"],
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#F44747",
            "fontStyle": "italic strikethrough"
        }
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

**Result**:

[image: result]